# Windows Phone 7 - dynamic items for a ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I want to create the content of the each item inside a `ListBox` dynamically - think of it as a list of items. Or think of a phone book application with contacts and each contact has one or more phone numbers that are displayed beneath the name; the name is one field, the phone numbers is a second field. But the content of the phone number field would obviously depend on the number of phone number the contact has.

Like:

```
Andrew Adams   <-- TextBlock for name
650-123-2222   <-- "Item" for numbers
490-222-3333

Benny Benjamin
650-123-3333
```

I have tried to solve this by creating a second `ListBox` for the numbers item inside the main `ListBox` item. But I don't know how I can populate this second `ListBox` with a model from C#.

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

            <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Margin="24,0" Height="620">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Name="ContactName" Text="{Binding ContactName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                            <ListBox Name="NumbersList" ItemsSource="{Binding NumbersList}">
                                <TextBlock Name="Number" Text="{Binding Number}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Question would be: How can I set `NumbersList` ItemsSource from C#? Or can I solve my problem with some other better approach?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, can you provide the model that you use to 'back' this view?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to set the model in the first place for this kind of structure (I can populate the outer ListBox, but I don't know how to populate the inner ListBox). I think that is my real issue :)

Comment: Just to be clear; NumbersList in the Contacts model is a public ObservableCollection<NumberInfo> NumbersList. NumberInfo exposes property Number. Should it work like that...?

Comment: Yes - you are doing everything right! Do you get any binding errors if you look in the debug window?

Comment: Yes, I get binding error: System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Number' property not found on 'TestApp.DataModels.Contact' 'TestApp.DataModels.Contact' (HashCode=65718800). BindingExpression: Path='Number' DataItem='TestApp.DataModels.Contact' (HashCode=65718800); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='Number'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..

Comment: The binding error doesn't quite make sense when compared to your XAML in your question. Can you update your question to include the DataModels that you are binding to this XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemTemplate` for your second `ListBox`. It should look like:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

        <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Margin="24,0" Height="620">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="ContactName" Text="{Binding ContactName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                        <ListBox Name="NumbersList" ItemsSource="{Binding NumbersList}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Name="Number" Text="{Binding Number}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

On a side note, don't give your UI elements name (Name or x:Name) unless you need to use them in code behind or from xaml. This is especially true for items within an ItemTemplate.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Such a stupid mistake and I bet I could have stared at the code and would not have seen this and only wondered about the binding errors. It works now!

Comment: If I may ask about your side note; is this because of performance? It's just a bad habit of mine from other platforms. Thanks for the note!

Comment: It won't hinder performance, it's just a bad habit to get into. When in the context of an ItemTemplate, there are many Items, and therefore many items named "Foo". If you are not accessing that item through some means (eg Binding, Triggers) then remove it. It's more for readability of the xaml than anything else

Answer (score 0):

- The inner  can't directly contain a
- If NumbersList is an IList or similar, then you can't bind to "Number" - simply use {Binding} instead

Comment: NumbersList is ObservableCollection<NumberInfo> NumbersList and NumberInfo exposes a property called Number. But as I commented above, I get the binding error which suggests that inner ListBox doesn't fetch the correct data model / property...